# get pairwise difference from emmeans with quadratic covariate interaction

Tags: r, compare, emmeans, poly, bonferroni

I have a factor X with three levels and a continuous covariate Z.

To predict the continuous variable Y, I have the model

`model<-lm(Y ~ X*poly(Z,2,raw=TRUE))`

I know that the emmeans package in R has the function emtrends() to estimate the pairwise difference between factor level slopes and does a p-value adjustment.

`emtrends(model, pairwise ~ X, var = "Z")`

however this works when Z is a linear term. Here I have a quadratic term. I guess this means I have to look at pairwise differences at pre specified values of Z? and get something like the local "slope" trend?

Is this possible to do with emmeans? How would I need to do the p-adjustment, does it scale with the number of grid points? -so when the number of grid values where I do the comparison increases, bonferroni will become too conservative?

Also how would I do the pairwise comparison of the mean (prediction) at different grid values with emmeans (or is this the same regardless of using poly() as this relies only on model predicitons)?

thanks.

Comment: add `, at = list(Z = <values you want>)` to the emtrends call

Comment: thanks . but let's assume I evaluate this at 1000 points then after p value corrections nothing will be significant anymore. Is there a way to do some 'omnibus' test if the pairwise compared polynomials differ?

Comment: No prob. Do `emt <- emtrends(...)`, then `test(emt, joint = TRUE)`. Then if you like, do the non-joint tests: `test(emt, adjust = "scheffe", scheffe.dim = <num.df>)` using the numerator df from the joint test.